# ASP .NET Core 5 - Individual accounts - wher is the user class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing an mvc app in .net core 5 (it is an online click-based rpg). I have decided to choose individual accounts athutentication at the start.
I have alter-tabled the initial AspNetUser table to have a foreign key of another table (I want a user to have a character linked to it).
Now I have a view which needs altering based upon logged in user having or not having a character. I know I have to go with seme kind of viewmodel. But the problem is that I have no access to the original class which the AspNetUser table was maped from. It is just not be found in the code. I assume the class does not exist and Visual Studio just gave a cue to my database to create those tables. But I need such class to exist in order to carry on with my coding.
What would you suggest I do now please?
Is there a way to make Visual Studio create necessary classes from the tables?
Thank you and have a grand day.

Comment: Given that .NET 5 is either already out of support or soon will be, you should go straight to .NET 6.

Comment: Look into the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager` class. I believe that it will provide access to the default user type, although you can tell your application to use your own types if you set it up properly. I suggest that you do some research on Identity and how to customise it.

Comment: Maybe you can name the class that extends the IdentityUser class , include as many properties as you want.  Like：“public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}”

Comment: @John thank you I did not honestly notice. When I go to the new version, do you think it that there will be better tools to help me solve my issue?

Comment: I don't think that much, if anything, will have changed in that regard but I don't think there's anything wrong with the tools already available. You just need to understand how Identity works.

Comment: @John pretty please, where can I find `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager` class? Im pretty new to this and a quick google search seldom helps. Thank you.

Comment: `UserManager` is part of [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). I suggest that you do some reading on that so that you have a better understanding of the subject as a whole, rather than trying to get it bit by bit. There will still likely be questions, but you'll have a better idea of what you don't know.